# Counting the number of records in a related table - going round in circles

Tags: django, join, annotate

I have viewed about 50 Stack Overflow questions as well as numerous Google articles but my head is hurting and I'm just not getting this.

I have the following database tables and fields:

```
Cases:
--id
--Name

Information:
--id
--case_id
--detail
```

What I want to do is to count how many information records there are for each case.

So in psuedo code it would be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Information WHERE case_id=id
```

Or similar.  My desired output is something like:

Case#1 has 43 information records
Case#2 has 16 information records
Case#3 has 8 information records

etc...

I have tried mainly using the annotate function in django, and then specifying foreign keys in the models.py file.

I think I have confused myself though as I have tried so many things now.

views.py:

```py
def cases(request):
    #didnt work - number = Cases.objects.annotate(Count('id'))

    #didn't work - questions = Information.objects.annotate(number_of_information_records=Count('id'))


    #didn't work - results = Information.objects.annotate(number_of_information_records=Count((Case(When(Cases.id == Information.case_id), output_field=IntegerField()))))
```

models.py:

```py
class Cases(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Case_Name', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.

    ##this was an attempt to get it to work
    ##information = models.ForeignKey("Information", on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="id")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Cases'
        verbose_name_plural = "Cases"

class Information(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    case_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Case_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Information'
        verbose_name_plural = "Information"
```

The code just doesn't work, it will often run without error but not output anything, or will output just objects without the detail I want.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Comment: Hi, 

I have this in the Case class within models.py:

information= models.ForeignKey("Information", on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="id")

Guess i may need another Foreign key though

Comment: I don't understand that comment. But please clarify via edits, not comments. PS FKs are not needed to query in SQL. You might want fields associated with one in an ORM to make use of automatic query/command compostion.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Information.objects.filter(case_id='foo'
).annotate(case_count=Count('case_id', filter=Q(case_id='foo'))
```

Got this answer from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this using [**`count`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#count):

```
Information.objects.filter(case_id=your_case_id).count()
```

Comment: Hey this worked - thanks!  

On additional question, I am struggling to loop through each case as it outputs.  

So basically, I want to load all the cases up and for each case I want to look up the number of Information objects.  In normal Python I would make my own function but I'm a bit unsure whether that is the proper way with Django

Comment: As far as your model, you don't have a ForeignKey relationship between Case and Information. So I don't think it will work like that. So either change it to FK to use .annotate or you need to do it manually, which will increase DB hit.